# Exctracting specific columns from different excel sheets (but same excel file) in R

Tags: r, excel, merge, tidyverse

I am struggling with merging a number of excel sheets into one data frame(or tibble). What I have is an excel file containing 21 sheets, each of the sheets has the same 2 columns which are identical in all the 21 sheets. But now I don't know how to tackle this in the most efficient way. Number of rows is the same in every sheet.

After I have done merging the sheets I wanted to select a number of the columns with dplyr::select to only choose specific columns.

I don't have enough experience to handle this myself, how would you tackle it?
Columns are our clients, and each of the observations is their energy demand per 15 min. So all the observations are of the same data type.

I have tried to make a tibble with the following names:

```
>colnames(test)
[1]"X871691600001976087" 
[2]"X871691600001837791"  etc
```

I have a list of column names that I want to extract:

```
>testnames
[1]"X871685900000003968"
[2]"X871685900000009600"  etc
```

Some of those column names will have to match, but they don't. I get this error:

```
selecttest <- select(test, one_of(testnames))    
"Warning message:
    Unknown variables: `871685900000003968`, etc.. (variables from testnames)"
```

Is this any sufficient information to get a hint here?

Comment: So is this right: your end goal is a table with only the columns whose names are in `testnames`? Is the selecting part the problem or is reading and combining each sheet also causing you problems?

Comment: Actually both of them :(
So what i have done is making an excel reading function:
gimmesheets<-function(x){
readxl("path.xls", sheet=x)
}
And given that i have 21 of the sheets, i have made an entity numberofsheets<-c(1:21)
Then i used test<-lapply(numberofsheets, gimmesheets)
It gave me a large list. Then i used as.data.frame(allsheets)
So in the end i have my dataframe with all the columns.
Then i tried to use dplyr select function.. and this is where i got the error messages. 
I am not so sure how to solve this.
So it could be that did something wrong when merging columns..

Comment: Are you sure they match? What does `colnames(test) %in% testnames` give?